# Is there a way to run parallel cucumber tests providing different users to each process

Tags: ruby, cucumber, parallel-testing

Problem to solve: We want to be able to run multiple ruby cucumber tests in parallel with different users. Since we have user collision in the app, we are not able to use the same user simultaneously. 
We tried looking into parallel_test gem to use parallel_cucumber but did not find any way to pass a different user for each process. One option I read online was to have user info in the DB and make a call to get a free user before each test. This was not feasible for us.

Does anyone know any way to make parallel_cucumber or any other ruby gem work to run parallel cucumber tests with a different user for each process

Answer (score 0):

If you are running parallel tests you should be able to use a separate db for each stream. This should avoid the issue of user collisions.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. When you say DB for each stream, do you mean a separate app instance with its own DB for each process. This would require us to pass different urls for each process. Apologies if I have got it wrong. Also using parallel cucumber I didnt see any way of passing different values for each process eg process1 - email1 & url1 | process2 - email2 & url2

Comment: see https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests. ParallelTests uses 1 database per test-process.